# Instructions execution order with SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following code with a function called things (called multiple times in a loop) calling the InsertOnSubmit function, adding the entity, that is going to be inserted, in a list. The elements of the list have their properties A and B modified. After a hundred calls to SubmitCounter, the changes are submitted.

```
static int counter = 0;
static void Things()
{
    List<TABLE> entityList = new List<TABLE>;
    entityList = EntityLoad();

    dbContext.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    SubmitCounter();

    entityList.Add(entity) 

    foreach(TABLE entity in entityList)
    {
        [...]

        entity.PROPERTYA = aVariable;
        entity.PROPERTYB = anotherVariable;

        SubmitCounter();
    }
}

static void SubmitCounter()
{
    counter++;

    if(counter >= 100)
    {
        dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Do you know if the instructions are performed in the order they are "submitted" in the program execution or do we have the inserts first, for example ?

It is, ultimately, to figure out if the result from the code above (being an optimization attempt of the code below) would be different from the result of the following code :

```
static int counter = 0;
static void Things()
{
    List<TABLE> entityList = new List<TABLE>;
    entityList = EntityLoad();

    dbContext.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();

    entityList.Add(entity) 

    foreach(TABLE entity in entityList)
    {
        [...]

        entity.PROPERTYA = aVariable;
        entity.PROPERTYB = anotherVariable;

        dbContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Usually relying on the order of rows in a table is a bad idea, as it is not guranateed to be the same, depending on the DB-System you use. Why do you even care about that?

Comment: I tried that to reduce the amount of transactions (as SubmitChanges is called around 10k times in the second solution) with the database and reduce the execution time of the program. I'll try to measure the difference in execution time between the two implementations.

Comment: I would suspect that the time to create and commit 10000 sql transactions would be quiet significant. But you might also hit a problem where SubmitChanges gets slower and slower unless you create a new DataConnection.